# I wanted to decrypt a message using RSA Public Key in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, rsa

I am new to Swift Language . I wanted a swift code for decrypting a message using RSA Public key.
Padding used is "PKCS1". (I am not talking about Signature , I want the code for decryption of message itself using Public Key) .
Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's not how RSA works. Signatures are made with private key and verified by public keys, while data encryption is done with the public keys and only the private key can decipher the message. I suggest reading about how RSA actually works first.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted a swift code for decrypting a message using RSA Public key.

What you are asking for is not possible.

With RSA public keys are used to encrypt messages, while the private key is used to decrypt encrypted messages. It's the other way around with signatures, and probably the reason why you are confused. Signatures are created using the private key and can be verified by public keys.